# Import error:No module named

Tags: python, import, python-import, importerror

I installed a cryptographic framework [Charm](https://github.com/JHUISI/charm) which is coded in Python. Then, I used it in my code by importing some tools as below:

```
from charm.toolbox.pairinggroup import PairingGroup,ZR,G1,G2,GT,pair
from charm.zkp_compiler.zkp_generator import *
```

However, I received an error

```
ImportError: No module named engine.protocol
```

`engine.protocol` used by `zkp_generator`. I do not receive any `Import Error` related with `charm.toolbox.pairringgroup`. What causes this? I don't think I have a problem related with pathing since I do not have the same problem with `charm.toolbox.pairringgroup` .

Comment: so why are you importing this in the first place if it works without it?

Answer (score 1):

According to the [official package structure](https://jhuisi.github.io/charm/packages.html), they introduced some changes in `v0.42b` that are not backwards compatible. I assume removing `charm.core.engine.protocol` is one of them.

If your application works without the `import`, why are you using it?

Comment: I edited my question. Actually `zkp_generator` uses `engine.protocol` and I need to use `zkp_generator`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems apparent that there is no module called charm.core.engine.protocol. One way to try and work to the bottom of this is if you in a command prompt call.

```
import charm.core.engine
dir (charm.core.engine) # Might not actually tell you anything useful
help (charm.core.engine) # If the documentation is good, might tell you what modules you can import
```

This might help, but from the above error charm.core.engine.protocol doesn't seem to exist...

Comment: When I execute this code, I see that charm.core.engine is stored in the packages of Python. It gives the path of the file and some other information as well.

Comment: Given your new error message, I think my other answer will help you more. The above is just to give you some idea of what is in it. If in the dir you can see protocol, then my other answer is highly likely to be correct.

Answer (score 0):

From the edit to your question, it seems to be expecting an object engine.protocol, which therefore means your code may well work with

```
from charm.core import *
```

This may well lead to an object called engine which has an attribute protocol (which can be called engine.protocol).